# Separate tables from splitting comma separated strings

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to take two comma separated strings and split them into two separate tables to use later for comparison reasons. Below is as close as I have gotten to this point. Both strings are being put into the same table, which honestly would work in the case I need it for, but it is a very clunky solution.

I tried to change the name of the table from 'TEST' to something else in the second loop, but I always got a compile error. Does someone know a more elegant solution?

```
    DECLARE
    L_INPUT_LOG VARCHAR2(25) := 'Error,Audit';
    L_INPUT_MOD VARCHAR(4000) := 'MODULE1,MODULE2';
    L_COUNT BINARY_INTEGER;
    LOG_TYPE_ARRAY DBMS_UTILITY.LNAME_ARRAY;
    APP_MODULE_ARRAY DBMS_UTILITY.LNAME_ARRAY;
    BEGIN
       DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE(LIST => REGEXP_REPLACE(L_INPUT_LOG, '(^|,)', '\1x'), TABLEN => L_COUNT, TAB => LOG_TYPE_ARRAY);
       DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE(LIST => REGEXP_REPLACE(L_INPUT_MOD, '(^|,)', '\1x'), TABLEN => L_COUNT, TAB => APP_MODULE_ARRAY);
       FOR I IN 1 .. L_COUNT
       LOOP
         INSERT INTO TEST VALUES
           (SUBSTR(LOG_TYPE_ARRAY(I), 2) );
         COMMIT;
      END LOOP;
      FOR I IN 1 .. L_COUNT
      LOOP
         INSERT INTO TEST VALUES
           (SUBSTR(APP_MODULE_ARRAY(I), 2) );
             COMMIT;
          END LOOP;
        END;
```

UPDATE: Below is the error that I am getting when I try to change the table TEST in the second loop. Asked for by MaxU

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DECLARE
L_INPUT_LOG VARCHAR2(25) := 'Error,Audit';
L_INPUT_MOD VARCHAR(4000) := 'MODULE1,MODULE2';
L_COUNT BINARY_INTEGER;
LOG_TYPE_ARRAY DBMS_UTILITY.LNAME_ARRAY;
APP_MODULE_ARRAY DBMS_UTILITY.LNAME_ARRAY;
BEGIN
   DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE(LIST => REGEXP_REPLACE(L_INPUT_LOG, '(^|,)', '\1x'), TABLEN => L_COUNT, TAB => LOG_TYPE_ARRAY);
   DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE(LIST => REGEXP_REPLACE(L_INPUT_MOD, '(^|,)', '\1x'), TABLEN => L_COUNT, TAB => APP_MODULE_ARRAY);
   FOR I IN 1 .. L_COUNT
   LOOP
     INSERT INTO TEST VALUES
       (SUBSTR(LOG_TYPE_ARRAY(I), 2) );
     COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
  FOR I IN 1 .. L_COUNT
  LOOP
     INSERT INTO GRIM VALUES
       (SUBSTR(APP_MODULE_ARRAY(I), 2) );
     COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 18, column 18:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 18, column 6:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: If this works, and you are getting an error changing only the name of the table, maybe such a table does not exist, or you don't have rights to insert

Comment: Rights are fine, I am logging in as the admin for this particular DB (Development). It just seems strange that the only table name I can use is 'TEST'

Comment: what is the error? are you doing it in SP or function?

Comment: It will be in a stored Procedure and I posted the exact error in an edit...

Answer (score 0):

> There can be multiple reasons for which the issue can arise.
>
> 1) If the 'TEST' table created in the same schema from where you
>   executing the script?
>
> If NO Try providing schema_name.TEST and if you are relying on ROLES
>   for GRANT here it wont work. So you need to provide the DIRECT OBJECT
>   level GRANTS to access the table.

```
Try GRANT SELECT,insert,update,delete ON SCHEMA.TEST TO <USER>;
```

> Hope this helps.